# Applying conditional trimmed mean in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am trying to achieve 80% trimmed mean for every group in scala to get rid of the outliers. But this has to applied only if the number of records are atleast more than 10 in that group.

Example,

```
val sales = Seq(
  ("Warsaw", 2016, 100),
  ("Warsaw", 2017, 200),
  ("Boston", 2015, 50),
  ("Boston", 2016, 150),
  ("Toronto", 2017, 50)
).toDF("city", "year", "amount")
```

So in this dataset, if i am doing a group by on this,

```
val groupByCityAndYear = sales
  .groupBy("city", "year").count() 
  .agg(avg($"amount").as("avg_amount"))
```

So in this case, if the count is more than 10, then should remove outliers (may be trimmed 80% mean), else directly avg($"amount"). How can i achieve this?

Here is the right explanation for trimmed mean I got, to explain this scenario,

Consider what a trimmed mean is: In the prototypical case, you first sort your data in increasing order. Then you count up to the trimming percentage from the bottom and discard those values. For example a 10% trimmed mean is common; in that case you count up from the lowest value until you've passed 10% of all the data in your set. The values below that mark are set aside. Likewise, you count down from the highest value until you've passed your trimming percentage, and set all values greater than that aside. You are now left with the middle 80%. You take the mean of that, and that is your 10% trimmed mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with window function, but will be expensive:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("city", "year").orderBy("amount")

sales
  .withColumn("rn", row_number().over(w))
  .withColumn("count", count("*").over(w))
  .groupBy("city", "year")
  .agg(avg(when(
    ($"count" < 10) or ($"rn" between($"count" * 0.1, $"count" * 0.9)), 
    $"amount"
  )) as "avg_amount")
```